# Is showing $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole in the real domain applicable to the complex domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

Can the following simple "squeeze theorem" be used to show the Riemann zeta function's singularity is a simple pole of order 1, with the derivation being done entirely in the real domain?

The method is inspired by a question: [Why does $\frac{s}{s-1} > \zeta(s) > \frac{1}{s-1}$ imply $\lim_{s \to 1^{+}}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133870/why-does-fracss-1-zetas-frac1s-1-imply-lim-s-to-1s?rq=1)

---

**Step 1**

The inequality is derived in the real domain by comparing the sum $\sum1/n^s$ to the integral $\int 1/x^sdx$.

$$\boxed{\frac{1}{s-1}<\zeta(s)<\frac{1}{s-1}+1}$$

The derivation (eg [here](https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/02/integral-comparison-tests.html)) is for real $s$.

---

**Step 2**

It is then simple algebra to show

$$1<(s-1)\zeta(s)<s$$

which, again, is for real $s$.

As $s\rightarrow 1^+$,

$$1<(s-1)\zeta(s)<1$$

---

**Step 3**

We know $\zeta(s)$ has a singularity at $s=1$, so the above shows it is a removable pole of order 1, a simple pole.

---

**Question:**

This analysis was done entirely in the real domain. Is the result valid when we consider $s$ to be complex?

If yes, this seems an easy to way to show the Riemann Zeta function's pole is of order 1.

Comment: What you wrote at the end of step 2 makes no sense. If you let $s\to 1+$, $s$ cannot appear in your result. Also, there is no real number strictly between $1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, that argument is not valid. If $a \in \Bbb R$ and $f$ is holomorphic in $B_r(a) \setminus \{ a \}$ then the existence of
$$
 \lim_{x \to a, x \in \Bbb R} (x-a)f(x)
$$
does not imply that $f$ has simple pole at $a$. A counterexample is
$$
 f(z) = \frac 1z + e^{-1/z^2}
$$
which has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: thanks for this helpful comment. I am therefore puzzled by the result from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133870/why-does-fracss-1-zetas-frac1s-1-imply-lim-s-to-1s?rq=1 that $(s-1)\zeta(s)=$ by the squeeze theorem, which suggests the singularity is a removable pole of rider 1. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Tariq: In that question it is shown that $\lim_{s \to 1^{+}}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$ and the notation $\lim_{s \to 1^{+}}$ implies that the limit is for *real* numbers $s$, approaching $s=1$ from the right. It is not claimed or shown that $\lim_{s \to 1}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$ for *complex* values of $s$.

Comment: Martin -  if a pole and its order is established in the real domain, surely it applies in the complex domain too?

Comment: @Tariq: I can only answer what you have asked, and the existence of $\lim_{s \to 1^{+}}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$ is *not* sufficient to prove that a function has a simple pole, as I demonstrated with an example.